# mybatis memcached cache failover

Tags: memcached, mybatis, cache-failover

We're considering using `memcached` as a distributed cache for `mybatis` (the MyBatis-Memcached
integration module).

Does anyone know how to configure it so that the `memcached` servers are not single points of failure? Currently, if I configure multiple `memcached` servers, the cache requests are hashed out to the servers, but each server is a single point of failure (i.e. if one goes down, the app will fail).

We would like that if one of the `memcached` servers goes down, that the `mybatis` client treats this cache as lost, continues working and builds the cache back up on another available `memcached` server.

Anyone any experience with this?